# How to execute methods after the OnCreateView?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, fragment

I'm working on an Android app in Java where a class is called and measurements are made in the OnCreateView method. However I have to automate the sending of his measurements once finished. But I can not. Is there a method inherited from :
java.lang.Object
↳ android.app.Fragment
which could execute functions after the OncreateView process.
Because for the moment the data are sent but have not had time to be filled.

Thanks for you help

Comment: It's best to work with Mutable LiveData to push data from model to viewModel. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData

Comment: onViewCreated ?

Comment: Override `onStart()`?